# Equation of rotated surface

Tags: rotations

I would like to determine the equation of a disk localized on y-z plane rotated around of the z-axis a $\theta$ angle. Could you tell me how to start?

The equation of the disk is

$$(y-a) ^ 2 + (z-a) ^ 2 <= r ^ 2$$

Could you tell me how to start the problem?

Comment: Please clarify, are you sure the equation is correct. 2 or 3 dimensions? What is $a$, assume circle's centre? A sketch could help.

Comment: hi, three dimensions, the disk is localized on y-z plane